# I have a SQL query which is for Jsonb type column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Here I am stuck in some situation where I need to add a SQL query in my operator list. I am confused how to do that.

Here is my query:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM rulesets WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(rulesets.rules) AS elem
    WHERE elem.value IN ('2c084b4e-9658-4f50-afe4-a0a820d1d51d', 
        '23de26ef-c3aa-4f31-81dd-1b63e1e2f699',
        '7a1af945-c5bd-4709-b5f3-24180398da7d', 
        '665ecd7e-900a-4b30-b6da-19ff7a0068b3')
) AND client_id='10001' AND is_deleted=false;"""
```

And I have to add this query in this operators list:

```
OPERATORS = {
    'is_null': lambda f, a: f.is_(None) if a else f.isnot(None),
    'eq': lambda f, a: f == a,
    'ne': lambda f, a: f != a,
    'gt': lambda f, a: f > a,
    'lt': lambda f, a: f < a,
    'gte': lambda f, a: f >= a,
    'lte': lambda f, a: f <= a,
    'like': lambda f, a: f.like(a),
    'ilike': lambda f, a: f.ilike(a),
    'not_ilike': lambda f, a: ~f.ilike(a),
    'in': lambda f, a: f.in_(a),
    'list_in': lambda f, a: f.contains(a),
    'or': lambda f, a: f.or_(a),
    'not_in': lambda f, a: ~f.in_(a),
    'nin': lambda f, a: ~f.in_(a),
    'any': lambda f, a: f.any(a),
    'not_any': lambda f, a: func.not_(f.any(a)),
}
```

I need your help adding that query to this list. If anyone can help me, please do.

I have tried to add the query list in the operator but I am not getting the correct result. This the line of code what I have tried to add that in the list:

```
'custom_query': lambda f, a: f.exists().where(and_(exists().where(jsonb_array_elements_text(f.rules).in_(a)), f.client_id == '10001', f.is_deleted == False)),
```

Comment: So you should really stop starting every single sentence with "so" .....

Comment: The question is unclear. What language are you using? This looks like Python and SQLAlchemy. Are you asking how to rewrite the SQL query as a SQLAlchemy query? What does `OPERATORS` have to do with the question?

Comment: If you're looking to incorporate custom logic or complex queries that can't be directly represented as a lambda function in the OPERATORS dictionary, you might consider handling these cases outside of the dictionary and using a more traditional function or method to execute the complex logic. For complex queries involving JSONB or other advanced SQL features, it's often cleaner and more maintainable to encapsulate this logic in a dedicated method or function where you can use the full power of SQLAlchemy or your ORM's query building tools without trying to fit it into a lambda function.